# Unity 3D: Footstep sounds looping the first few milliseconds instead of playing the full sound then looping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

When I move in game, instead of my sound being played in full, it is playing just a few milliseconds on a loop.

Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Footsteps : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource audioSource;

    public PlayerMovement pM;

    void Start()
    {
        audioSource.Stop();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        PlaySound();
    }

    public void PlaySound()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            audioSource.Play();
        }
        else
        {
            audioSource.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Video [Example](http://%20%3Chttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uHqoqIjncbA%3E).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `Input.GetKey()` is called as long as the key is pressed. To do that you want, you could use `Input.GetKeyDown()` like this example:

```
    public void PlaySound()
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
            {
                audioSource.Play();
            }
            else if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W))
            {
                audioSource.Stop();
            }
        }
```

There are other ways to to this kind of sounds, but this simple way should work.

References:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html

Answer (score 0):

As @Jamarin mentioned, you can use the moving keys to add the footstep sound.

I just added a list with all moving keys to give a complete solution.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Footsteps : MonoBehaviour
{
    List<UnityEngine.KeyCode> keys = new List<UnityEngine.KeyCode>();

    void Start()
    {
        keys.Add(KeyCode.W);
        keys.Add(KeyCode.S);
        keys.Add(KeyCode.A);
        keys.Add(KeyCode.D);
        keys.Add(KeyCode.UpArrow);
        keys.Add(KeyCode.DownArrow);
        keys.Add(KeyCode.LeftArrow);
        keys.Add(KeyCode.RightArrow);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (keys.Exists(key => Input.GetKeyDown(key)))
        {
            // PLUS: Change footstep sound to simulate a different kind of footstep.
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().volume = Random.Range(0.8f, 1);
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().pitch = Random.Range(0.8f, 1.1f);

            GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
        }

        if (keys.Exists(key => Input.GetKeyUp(key)))
        {
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Reference:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ih8gyGeC7xs